# Recognize a figure - Similar to the Magic Touch game

Tags: android, touch

In the game i need to the user to draw a figure, for example a rectangle, and the game has to recognize the figure. How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like you would want to use a Neural Network. If you don't know what that is: It is basically an Artificial Brain which can do simple tasks like classifying (recognizing) shapes. It's really easy to do with tensorflow, since it's easily integratable into Android: https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/android_build

Then, you would train your classifier to differenciate between Circle, Rectangle, Triangle and more. For this, you should draw some rectangles and triangles in your app, save them as images and label them yourself with what is in them. Then you can use those images with TensorFlow to train your AI to recognize images the user draws.

Comment: I believe it is not exactly that, I know how the process of neural networks works, what I want is similar to this game: Magic Touch: Wizard for Hire.

In this game the user drags the finger on the phone making drawings similar to the one presented by the game